# SwiftUI ForEach views not updating for the first time

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm trying to populate a group of views using ForEach. I've used Alamofire for fetching the data and setting the @State property to trigger an update. Unfortunately, the updates only show up when I switch screens(Using a TabBar) or go to the home screen and re-open the app.

Following is the code snippet that I've used:

```
@State var posts : [Post]
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView{
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0){
                ForEach(posts, id: \.id) { preview in
                    PreviewDetailView(preview: preview).background(Color(.white).cornerRadius(30))
                }
            }
        }.onAppear(perform: {fetchPosts()})
    }
```

Apparently, the `PreviewDetailView`(in which I'm displaying the API response data) gets triggered but the view doesn't update.

Comment: Did you see this: https://github.com/onmyway133/blog/issues/468 ?

Comment: No, but I'll try this one out. Thanks!. Though I also tried doing it without onAppear and used @ObservableObject and ObservedObject.

Answer (score 8):

The reason is when you use `stack` or `ForEach` within `ScrollView`, you have to setFrame limits to initialize the view Setting like the following.

```
ScrollView{
    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0){        
        ForEach(self.posts, id: \.id) { preview in
           PreviewDetailView(preview: preview)
               .background(Color(.red).cornerRadius(30))
        }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity) // Here
    }
}.onAppear{
    self.fetchPosts()   
}
```

Comment: Still no luck! The forEach subView's onAppear do get called but doesn't get displayed unless I switch the app to the background and then back to foreground.

Comment: It works for me. I think the reason is in scrolling view if there is no initial view, scrolling view is not sure about the future dimensions. You can put some holder or loading indicator inside the scrolling view. When the data is ready, it will update the view. How did you update your data? Now I am sure that’s the major reason!

Comment: Well, I just updated the "posts" property that you'd find in my code snippet. Simply did a self.posts = posts to update the API response. Anyways, your point of adding adding a placeholder view makes sense I'll try that out!

Comment: Even if I put a placeholder the ScrollView would just constrain it's self to those dimensions in the future. So if my ForEach has a larger list of views, a few of them won't be displayed. Still some progress!

Comment: Maybe it’s performance issue. Just use simple data not your data to isolate questions from Ui and data updating

Comment: Umm.. Not really. Essentially, the ScrollView requires a knowledge of the posts count to calculate the height in this case.

Comment: 2020 and this answer still works. As long as your data populates in the OnAppear it will work "first try". E. Coms is also correct, you can place dummy data if needed with a another constant list or something like that. UI errors after list is populated should be handled accordingly. Use Geometry View if needed, also don't forget to use .reverse() for ScrollViews in ios13 if you need the scrollview to "start from the bottom"

Comment: why maxWidth instead of maxHeight?

Answer (score 2):

I think, you have to check the "posts" object is not empty;

```
if !self.posts.isEmpty {
   ForEach(self.posts, id: \.id) { preview in
    PreviewDetailView(preview: preview)
        .background(Color(.red).cornerRadius(30))
   }
}
```

Comment: I think this answer is half right; checking if data used in `forEach` was already fetched is indeed the way to go, but `if` has to be used a bit earlier; before ScrollView, so scrollView will be attached only when data is present. Because like @Asperi mentioned - scrollView here is a true problem. What is funny, this seems to be fixed when running exactly the same code on iOS14.

Answer (score 1):

I can guess that your `posts` initially empty array... This is a (don't know feature or bug) of stand-along ForEach initialisation with empty container. BTW, with List everything ok in such case. Neither `@State`, nor `@ObservedObject`, nor `onAppear`, nor custom publisher influences or help here. Just empty container on start in ForEach.

**Workaround:** Use some initial stub Post in container, which can be just checked conditionally in view builder and not shown

Or use List instead of ScrollView/VStack/ForEach.

**UPDATE:** My bad... when I wrote this latest phrase, I've got a mind, that I aways used it in such combination `ScrollView/VStack/ForEach`... in short, the problem is in ScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to set a minHeight to the VStack like so:

```
ScrollView{
    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0){
        ForEach(self.posts, id: \.id) { preview in
            PreviewDetailView(preview: preview)
                .background(Color(.red).cornerRadius(30))
        }
    }.frame(minHeight: <some_reasonable_Float_value, minWidth: <same_here>)
}
```

Like some poster mentioned, the `ScrollView` doesn't know, ahead of time, what the dimensions of the items to be rendered will be, so it collapses on itself.